# How to remove padding from a UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, padding

I am new to iOS development and I couldn't find an answer online for this. So I have a UIView and I have a UITableView within that view. But for some odd reason the table view doesn't extend the full width of the parent UIView.

The red color is the UIView.

The green color is the UITableView.

[image]

Here are the constraints for the TableView

[image]

Here are the constraints for the UIView

[image]

How can I get the table view to have the full width of the device/the UIView
such that the only red visible is in the bottom and not on the sides as its currently shown in the picture?
(The horrible colors are just for visual explanation. Not going to keep them lol)

Comment: Please show your constraints.

Comment: You probably constrained to margins rather than the superview.

Comment: Added the constraints to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Storyboard:

1. Remove your current leading and trailing constraints of your table view, and leave your other constraints as they are.
2. From the bottom right of UI Builder, click on Add New Constraint pin, and **uncheck** *constrain to margins* then set your leading and trailing constraints to 0 and add them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove constrain to margins as already suggested. Next select the left, top, right, and bottom bar, and make sure that the left, top and right margin settings are set to 0 and select a value for the bottom margin. This will force the view to the edges of the superview.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNBfm.png